# why I can't use console.log in promise .then() method?

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

so I'm practicing `promise` concept and I've faced a issue in `promise`, I have implemented a code in two ways: first with promises and in the latter I've used callbacks, but the result is different, and still there is an issue with using `consol.log()` with `.then()`.

code :

with promise:

```js
let sample = new Promise((success) => {
  return success(3);
});

console.log(sample.then((x) => {
  return x;
}))

// result:promise object
```

with callback:

```js
function sample(callbackP) {
  return callbackP(3)
}

function callback(x) {
  return x;
}

console.log(sample(callback));
//result:3
```

if we use the promise scenario in this way again we don't get the exact result as we get with callbacks

```js
let sample = new Promise((success) => {
  console.log(success(3));
});

sample.then((x) => {
  return x;
})

// result:nothing
```

the only way I can get the exact output as in callbacks is with scenario below:

```js
let sample = new Promise((success) => {
  success(3);
});

sample.then((x) => {
  console.log(x);
})

// result:3
```

as far as I know first two scenarios (callback and promise) are same but why the result in promise scenario depends on the `console.log()` and `return` position while it shouldn't... because in callback scenario it's not like this... so I wonder why in promise scenario why the results are this diverse and different?

Comment: The `.then()` call returns a Promise.

Comment: The results aren't really "diverse and different", your initial attempts were simply mistakes.  You corrected the mistake in your last attempt.  The value you want to log is `x`, and you want to log that value in the `.then()` callback that follows the `Promise`.  The previous attempts were just fundamental misunderstandings of how any of this is structured, essentially putting `console.log` around random segments of code.

Comment: Your title describes what you want to do: call `console.log` **in** the `.then()` method. Your mistake is calling it **around** the method.

Comment: Aside: It's conventional to call the arguments of a Promise callback `resolve` and `reject`.

Comment: It seems you believe that the callback function passed to `then` is passed as the `success` parameter to the function in `new Promise`. That is false. The `new Promise` callback is executed immediately, before then `then` callback even exists, and it does not matter when or how many times the `.then()` method is invoked.

Comment: *"as far as I know first two scenarios (callback and promise) are same"*: they are not. Promises involve *jobs* that execute asynchronously, and callbacks don't. Your callback scenario executes synchronously. `then` callbacks are *always* executed some time *after* all synchronous code has been executed until the callstack is empty.

Answer (score -1):

You are a bit mistaken by what a Promise does.

Promises are asynchronous and that's why you have to use `.then` or use `async` and `await`. But let's focus on Promise in this case.

You can think of it as a blueprint of the logic you are about to execute once the promise resolves. You're asking javascript *"promise that something is done and `.then` do something with that result"*.

For example:

```
const timeoutPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
   setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000);
});

// Promise that the timeout is done, .then() do something else
timeoutPromise.then(() => {
   console.log("The timeout is done");
});
```

You can also chain the `.then()`'s. Every time you return a value in a then, that will be the argument of the next `.then()`.

In your case you could use:

```js
let sample = new Promise((resolve) => {
  return resolve(3);
});

sample.then((x) => {
   console.log(x);
});

// or shorter (because the first argument is also the first argument of console.log)

sample.then(console.log)
```

Promises can also fail (like an Error or manually calling `reject`). In this case the `.catch()` method is executed.

```js
let sample = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  return reject(3);
});

sample.then((x) => {
   console.log(x);
});

sample.catch((err) => {
   console.log("Error", err);
}).then(() => {
   console.log("Error logged, see above")
});
```

Note that `console.log(x)` will not be executed because the promise is rejected (or failed). The `.catch` method will be called and the error is logged.

Note that you also can call `.then()` after a catch (because a `.catch` will also return a new promise). Which will only be executed if the `catch` is executed, not when the original Promise is resolved.